# Custom object Cleaner for old JDK

Tags: java, jni

I'm implementing a JNI library that needs to dispose a few native objects after use. The main library class implements `Closeable` and is almost always used within try-with-resources. Even then, as the library will be used in by a larger audience within the company, I want to make a safe-guard to make it harder to introduce native memory leaks.

Initially I did this by implementing the `finalize()` method. But this was bad for two reasons:

- [Finalizers are deprecated since Java 9](https://openjdk.org/jeps/421) (in favor of Cleaners).
- After benchmarking it, finalizers were slowing down GC significantly. Even if all objects were explicitly closed before finalization.

Using Cleaners would be ok, but they are only available since Java 9, and my library needs to support Java 8. Besides, they keep the cleaner thread alive forever and I wanted something that allowed the cleaner thread to be killed if no new objects were pending finalization after `keepAlive` milliseconds. This is why I created the class `CleanerThread` below.

It contains a lot of code borrowed from `java.lang.ref.Cleaner` and also `sun.misc.Cleaner`, but with changes to allow the thread to be killed and respawned as needed. Please, keep in mind that `CleanerThread` is only meant to be used by library code (not user code). **I would appreciate feedback on potential bugs in this implementation**.

It should be used like this:

```java
public class Resource implements Closeable {
    private static final CleanerThread CLEANER = new CleanerThread(5000, "Cleanup Thread");
    private final CleanerThread.Cleaner cleaner;

    public Resource() {
        cleaner = CLEANER.register(this, new ResourceCleaningAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        cleaner.clean(); // preemptively clean resources
    }

    private static class ResourceCleaningAction implements CleanerThread.CleaningAction {
        @Override
        public void clean(boolean leak) {
            // perform cleaning actions
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `CleanerThread` implementation:

```java
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class CleanerThread {
    public interface Cleaner {
        void clean();
    }

    public interface CleaningAction {
        void clean(boolean leak);
    }

    private final ReferenceQueue<Object> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    private final long keepAlive;
    private final String name;
    private boolean threadRunning = false;
    private Node first;

    public CleanerThread(long keapAlive, String name) {
        this.keepAlive = keapAlive;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Cleaner register(Object obj, CleaningAction action) {
        Node node = new Node(obj, action);
        add(node);
        return node;
    }

    private synchronized boolean checkEmpty() {
        if (first == null) {
            threadRunning = false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private synchronized void add(Node node) {
        if (first != null) {
            node.next = first;
            first.prev = node;
        }
        first = node;

        if (!threadRunning) {
            threadRunning = true;
            startThread();
        }
    }

    private void startThread() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Node ref = (Node) queue.remove(keepAlive);
                    if (ref != null) {
                        ref._clean(true);
                    } else if (checkEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // ignore exceptions from the cleanup action
                    // (including interruption of cleanup thread)
                }
            }
        }, name);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private synchronized boolean remove(Node node) {
        // If already removed, do nothing
        if (node.next == node)
            return false;

        // Update list
        if (first == node)
            first = node.next;
        if (node.next != null)
            node.next.prev = node.prev;
        if (node.prev != null)
            node.prev.next = node.next;

        // Indicate removal by pointing the cleaner to itself
        node.next = node;
        node.prev = node;

        return true;

    }

    private class Node extends PhantomReference<Object> implements Cleaner {
        private final CleaningAction action;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        public Node(Object referent, CleaningAction action) {
            super(referent, queue);
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void clean() {
            _clean(false);
        }

        private void _clean(boolean leak) {
            if (!remove(this))
                return;
            try {
                action.clean(leak);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Should not happen if cleaners are well-behaved
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sincere question: it is worth and still correct to make the following refactoring? Btw, a nit: rename `checkEmpty()` to `isEmpty()`.

```
private synchronized boolean checkEmpty() {
    if (first == null) {
        threadRunning = false;
    }
    return !threadRunning;
}
```

Another question: what happens if it is passed null for the parameters below? I.e., does the method needs defensive null checking?

```
public Node(Object referent, CleaningAction action) {
```

Comment: The first one is interesting to reduce the source size, but it introduces a new field access, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: The second one is even more interesting. There is no problem in passing a null pointer here, but there is a lurking bug I found while analyzing that. `referent` can become unreachable before the constructor finishes running. I added a poor man's reachabilityFence in that constructor, which happens to be an `Objects.requireNonNull(referent)`. Thanks :D